# Need to print the below string as: 10-30 03:45:04.312 2760 2760 GrowthKit: job GrowthKit.PeriodicSyncJob failed E

Tags: java

string as

```
10-30 03:45:04.312  2760  2760  GrowthKit: job GrowthKit.PeriodicSyncJob   E
```

So the output should look as below

```
10-30
03:45:04.312  
2760  
2760   
GrowthKit: job GrowthKit.PeriodicSyncJob failed  
E
```

Need to be done with RegularExpression matcher and pattern.

Written code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "10-30 03:45:04.312  2760  2760  GrowthKit: job GrowthKit.PeriodicSyncJob E ";
    Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("^([a-zA-Z0-9]+).*");
    Matcher matcher = regex.matcher(s);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
            String[] words = matcher.group(i).split("\\s+");
            for (String line : words) {
                System.out.println("" + line);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Please provide us the solution for this:

Answer (score 1):

1. With a pattern that'll try to match the different elements you can `\s*([0-9-:.]+|[a-zA-Z:.\s+]+)\s*` , it'll match :

   - group of **number-:.**
   - group of **letter:.*space***

   It works for all, except the `E` alone at the end, I did not find the way to separe it

   ```
   Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("\\s*([0-9-:.]+|[a-zA-Z:.\\s+]+)\\s*");
   Matcher matcher = regex.matcher(s);
   while (matcher.find()) {
       String group = matcher.group().trim();
       System.out.println(group);
   }

   10-30
   03:45:04.312
   2760
   2760
   GrowthKit: job GrowthKit.PeriodicSyncJob E
   ```

---

2. If the whole String is always formatted the same, you can have a pattern than match it fully :

   ```
   Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("([0-9-:.]+)\\s+([0-9-:.]+)\\s+([0-9-:.]+)\\s+([0-9-:.]+)\\s+(\\b.*\\b)\\s+(\\w)");
   Matcher matcher = regex.matcher(s);
   while (matcher.find()) {
       for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
           System.out.println(matcher.group(i));
       }
   }

   10-30
   03:45:04.312
   2760
   2760
   GrowthKit: job GrowthKit.PeriodicSyncJob
   E
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks cisk,
i don't want to hardcore the values as "([0-9-:.]+)\s+([0-9-:.]+)\s+([0-9-:.]+)\s+([0-9-:.]+)\s+(\b.*\b)\s+(\w)");. as this way
If the string gets append with integer values at the last it should print correctly.
Can you propose another way of solution for this.